# How to apply `Convert-SidToName` to list of entries?

Tags: powershell

I use PowerView to enumerate active directory, and I have this collection of `SecurityIdentifiers`which I would like to convert to readable names using the PowerView function `Convert-SidToName`. I would expect Powershell can somehow pipe these values to the function, but can't figure out how:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> Get-ObjectAcl -Identity "DnsAdmins" | ? {$_.ActiveDirectoryRights -eq "GenericAll" } | select SecurityIdentifier

SecurityIdentifier                         
------------------                         
S-1-5-21-976142013-3766213998-138799841-512
S-1-5-32-548                               
S-1-5-18                                   
S-1-5-21-976142013-3766213998-138799841-519
```

Something like:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> Get-ObjectAcl -Identity "DnsAdmins" | ? {$_.ActiveDirectoryRights -eq "GenericAll" } | select SecurityIdentifier | Convert-SidToName
```

just gives a syntax error:

```
ConvertFrom-SID : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ObjectSid'. The argument 
"@{SecurityIdentifier=S-1-5-21-976142013-3766213998-138799841-519}" does not match the "^S-1-.*" pattern. Supply an 
argument that matches "^S-1-.*" and try the command again.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `select SecurityIdentifier` with `select -ExpandProperty SecurityIdentifier` to pipe the SID values as a list of strings instead of objects.

Depending on whether `ConvertFrom-SID` is written to accept a list of strings, you may need to replace the basic pipe with a foreach like  `| foreach { ConvertFrom-SID $_ }` as well.

---

As an alternative, you might prefer something like the built-in `Get-Acl` command using `ad:` paths instead, which automatically converts SID to ID when possible:

```
(Get-Acl -Path "ad:$((Get-ADGroup "DNSAdmins").DistinguishedName)").Access |
  ? {$_.ActiveDirectoryRights -eq "GenericAll" } | 
  select -Expand IdentityReference | sort

# result:

Value
-----------------                 
CONTOSO\Domain Admins             
CONTOSO\Enterprise Admins         
CONTOSO\Enterprise Key Admins     
etc...
```